# About awk shell and pipe in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

everyone, I am dealing with a log file which has about 5 million lines, so I use the awk shell in linux

I have to grep the domains and get the highest 100 in the log, so I write like this:

```
          awk '{print $19}' $1 | 
          awk '{ split($0, string, "/");print string[1]}' |
          awk '{domains[$0]++} END{for(j in domains) print domains[j], j}' |
          sort -n | tail -n 100 > $2
```

it runs about 13 seconds

then I change the script like this:

```
          awk 'split($19, string, "/"); domains[string[1]]++}
               END{for(j in domains) print domains[j], j}' $1 |
          sort -n | tail -n 100 > $2
```

it runs about 21 seconds

why?

you know one line of awk shell may reduce the sum of cal, it only read each line once, but the time increase...

so, if you know the answer, tell me

Comment: and how does your input data look like? what info you want to extract and save??

Comment: +1 for question, research and formatting! Did you run this more than once, maybe there was a high CPU task running to compete on 2nd run? Otherwise I agree with @rjack that splitting the job improved performance. Good luck:-)

Comment: it runs on a linux server which has the info: cpu: 8 * Intel(R) Xeon

Comment: I have ran it for many times, and my task have time limit, so I really care the run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pipe commands they run in parallel as long as the pipe is full.

So my guess is that in the first version work is distributed among your CPUs, while in the second one all the work is done by one core.

You can verify this with `top` (or, better, `htop`).

---

Out of curiosity, is this faster? (untested):

```
cut -f 19 -d' ' $1 | cut -f1 -d'/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 100 > $2
```

Comment: I would expect it to be slower, since the `sort` step touches a lot of memory (and at 5 million lines I expect it to be physical memory), while `awk` only touches approx _Number_of_different_domains_ * (_sizeof(number)_ + _average_sizeof_domain)_

Comment: I am still a little confused. You know the second  awk' input is the first awk's ouput , they must be in a order, how they run in parallel?How big is the pipe? the second awk begin to handle the unfinished input ???

Comment: "the second awk begin to handle the unfinished input ???"

yes, `awk` reads line by line, so the second invocation can start its work as long as there's one or more line in the pipe. OTOH, `sort` needs to read all its input and this breaks the pipeline.